# A quiestion about mcrouter, WarmUpRoute handle can not set multiple cold servers

Tags: memcached

I wanna use WarmUpRoute to prepare two cold memcached data node, I use this config:

```
{
"pools": {
    "cold": {
        "servers": ["xxxxx:11212", "xxxx:11213"]
    },
    "warm": {
        "servers": ["xxxxx:11211"]
    }
},
"route": {
    "type": "WarmUpRoute",
    "cold": "PoolRoute|cold",
    "warm": "PoolRoute|warm"
}
```

}

But when I do some test, I connet mcrouter and set some data, found that only 1 cold server and warm server are success to save data, another cold node cannot set data successfuly. I am confuse, my config has some problem or is this a bug?